# Get iframes closest div width always returns 0

Tags: jquery

I am writing a jquery script for my Joomla Template, to handle responsiveness and resizing of videos from YouTube.

In a page there can be more than 1 videos and may be embedded within different container elements, e.g div or p.

Now, in my script, I am getting the original dimensions of the iframes, then calculate their ratio, then get their container element width and calculate the new height attribute for the iframe.

My problem is that for the second iframe on the page I am working on, jQuery always returns a width of 0, no matter what.

When I try the code outside of Joomla, it works okay.

### Questions:

- What could be the reason, that jQuery refuses to calculate correctly the width of a closest('element') on my actual page, and always returns 0?
- Can you spot anything that is obvious wrong in my code?

### Code:

#### Html:

In that page of my site, there are 2 embedded YT videos, in different locations.
Here is the html around the iframes :

```
<div class="video-container youtube">
    <iframe id="myvideo" width="964" height="544" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Eol8eo4WDKY?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
<div class="item_desc">
    <p>
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JfOD35Ebo5A" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; "></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="video-container youtube">
    <iframe id="myvideo" width="964" height="544" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Eol8eo4WDKY?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

and here is the jQuery that's failing to calculate the width of the closest div of the second iframe in Joomla (but succeeds elsewhere: **http://jsfiddle.net/joomquery/Lc9z3pbv/**).

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {               
        $.fn.myfunction = function(e) {
            $(e).each(function(i){
                var orW = $(this).attr("width");
                var orH = $(this).attr("height");
                var ratio = orH/orW;
                var w  = $(this).closest("div").width();
                //alert (w);
                var h = ratio * w;
                h = Math.round(h);

                //alert ("Parent size: " + w + ' ' + h);

                $(this).parent().css('height',h+10);
                $(this).attr('width',w);
                $(this).attr('height',h);
            });
        }; 

    var iframe = $('iframe');
    $.fn.myfunction(iframe);

})(jQuery);
```

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.myfunction = function (e) {
            $(e).each(function (i) {
                var orW = $(this).attr("width");
                var orH = $(this).attr("height");
                var ratio = orH / orW;
                var w = $(this).closest("div").width();
                var h = ratio * w;
                h = Math.round(h);

                $(this).parent().css('height', h + 10);
                $(this).attr('width', w);
                $(this).attr('height', h);
            });
        };

        var iframe = $('iframe');
        $.fn.myfunction(iframe);

    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container youtube">
    <iframe id="myvideo" width="964" height="544" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Eol8eo4WDKY?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
<div class="item_desc">
    <p>
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JfOD35Ebo5A" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; "></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure in joomla is the same html? You can also try with `$(this).parents("div").width()`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, The html regarding the iframes and their around is the same. Of course the page has other html and the 2 iframes are not next to each other. I tried with parent() earlier :for the second iframe it was trying to calculate the p element) again I got 0. In Joomla, if I ask for the class name of the closest div, it actually returns the correct class name, and I also tried to get the width of the container with class name and again I got 0.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, $(this).parents("div").width(); also returns 0. Isn't supposed that it should be able to calculate the width of the parent,closest element, disregarding what that element is?